How to get the list of all widgets within the view port in Flutter?
I see there is a variable in test environment of Flutter called this:
tester.allWidgets

It can return all widgets within the view port at the moment.
Is there anyway I can do the same with Flutter code, not inside a unit test?
The specific requirement I have is to locate all scrollable widgets within the current view port. Wondering if there's an easy way to achieve that.

Can you tell us what you tried that didn't work? For example suggestions made by an AI?

no, there is no built-in mechanism for that - all you can do is to "listen" for ScrollController changes

@Texv I have tried both ChatGPT and Gemini, both have given some suggestions, but neither of them works. There're some syntax errors on their generated code and I can't run any of them. I can put them here if you want.

@pskink In that case, perhaps I need to listen to all scrollable widgets?

just do controller.addListener(_listener) and _listener will be called each time you scroll your ListView / SingleChildScrollView / whatever

use: https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector
VisibilityDetector will detect child's visibility. wrap the children with VisibilityDetector, and use a list to containing all show widget.
you will get list of

widget within the view port

here's a example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:visibility_detector/visibility_detector.dart';

class VisibleWidgetList extends StatefulWidget {
  const VisibleWidgetList({super.key});

  @override
  State<VisibleWidgetList> createState() => _VisibleWidgetListState();
}

class _VisibleWidgetListState extends State<VisibleWidgetList> {

  List<int> numbers = List.generate(100, (i) => i);

  List<Key> visibleWidgets = []; // visible children

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: numbers.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return VisibilityDetector(
            key: Key(index.toString()),
            onVisibilityChanged: (info) {
              if (info.visibleFraction > 0) {
                visibleWidgets.add(info.key);
              } else {
                visibleWidgets.remove(info.key);
              }

              print(visibleWidgets);
            },
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text('Item ${numbers[index]}'),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}



So each child widget will need its own visibility detector?

yes, I don't see there is any other way

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You can try element tree traversal.
You locate widgets within the element tree that are scrollable and are within the current viewport by checking their position and size constraints.
Here is a sample of how you would do it:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Find Scrollable Widgets in Viewport'),
        ),
        body: HomeScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Widget> scrollableWidgets = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      findScrollableWidgets();
    });
  }

  void findScrollableWidgets() {
    // Root element of the widget tree
    final element = context as Element;

    // List to hold scrollable widgets found
    final List<Widget> scrollables = [];

    // Function to recursively find scrollable widgets
    void findScrollableElements(Element element) {
      element.visitChildren((child) {
        if (child.widget is ScrollView) {
          final RenderBox renderBox = child.renderObject as RenderBox;
          if (renderBox.hasSize) {
            final Size size = renderBox.size;
            // Check if the render box is within the viewport
            if (size.height > 0 && size.width > 0) {
              scrollables.add(child.widget);
            }
          }
        }
        findScrollableElements(child);
      });
    }

    findScrollableElements(element);

    setState(() {
      scrollableWidgets = scrollables;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // A scrollable
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('Item $index'),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        // A scrollable
        Expanded(
          child: GridView.builder(
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
            ),
            itemCount: 20,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Center(child: Text('Card $index')),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('Found ${scrollableWidgets.length} scrollable widgets');
            for (var widget in scrollableWidgets) {
              print(widget.runtimeType);
            }
          },
          child: Text('Find Scrollable Widgets'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


We do a renderBox.hasSize to check if the RenderBox has been laid out by the framework and has a valid size.
We do a if (size.height > 0 && size.width > 0) to check if the RenderBox has a positive width and height as zero height or width means that the widget is not visible or not rendered within the current viewport.

Its either you do a Element Tree Traversal or a RenderObject Tree Traversal
